# how create a tinymce custom button to open e form with input radio but following Wordpress guideline

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I try to send in review a new wordpress plugin.
It's ok but wordpress answer me with an email where tell me to modify the way i create a Tinymce button to insert a shortcode in text editor.
In particular i need to show on click a form with 2 input type radio to allow user to select a shortocode. In particular i have two input radio, i select one of them and click on the submit button to insert selected shortcode in text.
With only one shortcode, it's very simple and there is a lot of documents on the network about it.
But the problem is when i have to select one of more shortcodes.
Could you help me with an example ?
Can i use windowManager with url ? In this case how can i pass the correct url tu js file ?
Please help me, i ha ve the review process of the plugin in pending.
Thanks and excuse me for my bad english.

Comment: A good example: [How to add a shortcode button to the TinyMCE editor?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72394/how-to-add-a-shortcode-button-to-the-tinymce-editor) . . . . Install an English spell checker in your browser, it helps to write better and learn at the same time ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link and excuse for my english..i wrote my post with phone :)

Comment: Mamma mia, Cesco, questo è un scandalo! Writing a question from the phone seems pretty ninja... You have to tell what exactly you have to modify and show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. . . . Asking for an example is off-topic, this site helps you to *fix your own code*.